# Django fixtures not accepting YAML?

Tags: django, yaml, fixtures

```
$ python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.yaml 
Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/initial_data': yaml is not a known serialization format.
$ 
$ python manage.py loaddata fixtures/initial_data.yml 
Problem installing fixture 'fixtures/initial_data': yml is not a known serialization format.
```

According to Django documentation this format should be supported, but I get the above  errors. JSON on the other hand works ok.

**Django version:**

> > > django.VERSION
> > >       (1, 3, 1, 'final', 0)

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

.yaml is what you want. Make sure YAML is installed and available to Python by running:

```
> pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: In case of Mac OS, you should install libyaml 1st -> port install libyaml.

Comment: or `brew install libyaml` if you use homebrew

Comment: Please note that only files with an "yaml" extension will be accepted as fixtures by Django (tested on Django 2.2). So initial_data.yaml will be loaded but initial_data.yml wont be loaded and an error will be thrown:  `CommandError: Problem installing fixture 'initial_data': yml is not a known serialization format.`

Answer (score 1):

debian based linux - ubuntu etc etc
`sudo apt-get install python-yaml`
or
`apt-get install python-yaml`